# Safari messes up code wrapping in a comment

Tags: bug, code-formatting, safari

I noticed that Safari Version 7.0.6 (9537.78.2) on Mac Mavericks messes up with `white-space: normal;` on code tags on [this very particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css#comment12614788_9884099) :

[image: Safari's fault]

While [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css#comment19702182_1033222) is fine. I can't figure it out.

<sup>Note : a real effort was made on the hand-drawn rectangle</sup>

Comment: There's a number of bugs with Safari and comment formatting.  Mine from Meta.Programmers.SE: [Missing and extra spaces in comments](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6948/40980)

Comment: @MichaelT Safari's strange sometimes...